# Unity. Геттер не присваивает объекту ссылку

Tags: unity3d

```
GameObject prefab = Instantiate(Resources.Load("UIPref/ScrollViewOfMenu") as Object, Canvas.transform) as GameObject;


GameObject Nickname = prefab.transform.Find("Nickname_text").gameObject; // Здесь ошибка !!!!
```

Ошибка: Ссылка на объект не задана чтобы инстанцировать (создать) этот объект. Указывает как раз таки на строку с GameObject Nickname.

В тоже время в справке по геттеру gameObject типа Transform написано о том что данный гетер возвращает: The game object this component is attached to. A component is always attached to a game object.

Вот и вопрос, почему данная строчка не работает?

---

```
// Немного позже я достиг результата следующим по сути типичным способом, однако мне интересно узнать причину того почему тот вариант выше не сработал:
// GameObject Nickname = GameObject.Find("Nickname_text");
```

Answer (score 2):

Во первых `геттер не присвивает` и точка. Присваивает сеттер!

Попробуй так:

```
GameObject Nickname = null;
Transform NicknameTransform = prefab.transform.Find("Nickname_text");
if (NicknameTransform != null)
    Nickname = NicknameTransform.gameObject;
if (Nickname == null)
     Debug.LogError("Nickname is null");
```

И угадай в чём была твоя ошибка.

Вообще Find ужасная штука и Resources тоже. В идеале всё должно быть так:

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class Foo : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ссылка на префаб в инспекторе, Resources это не удобно и косячно
    [SerializeField] private ScrollViewOfMenu _scrollMenuTemplate;
    // ссылка на канвас, но в идеале сам Foo должен быть на канвасе и без всяких ссылко Instantiate на свой transform
    [SerializeField] private Transform _canvas;
    private ScrollViewOfMenu _scrollMenu;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        _scrollMenu = Instantiate(_scrollMenuTemplate.gameObject, _canvas).GetComponent<ScrollViewOfMenu>();
        GameObject Nickname = _scrollMenu.Nickname;
    }
}
```

---

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class ScrollViewOfMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    // ссылка к дочернему объекту префаба задаётся в инспекторе, что бы его не искать
    public GameObject Nickname;
}
```

И эти префабы можно переименовывать и перемещать по папкам проекта как хочешь не устраивая мусорный полигон `Эко-Техно-Парк "Resources"`.

Comment: Ну это же бред блин.... но вроде я понял. Хотя будет бредово если заработает)))
P.S> геттер возвращает присваивая =)) 

Щас проверю.

Comment: Бред это пытаться обращаться к полю/свойству или вызывать метод не существующего объекта. P.S> Ok Google Translater: get>получать set>устанавливать.

Comment: Не работает. Пишет что Nickname is null. пзд... Я не понимаю что не так то. Я знаю что get это получать. Но возвращает то он GameObject, присваивая его объекту левостороннего выражения. Я ровно такой же пример использовал и все работало... Я полагаю он с префабом не хочет работает просто...

Comment: Ты просто ошибся с путём к префабу или имени. Лучше делай как в моём примере, без всяких строковых.

Comment: В итоге получается код был рабочий. Суть в том что Find от трансформера оказывается не ищет по всем папкам а ищет только на том уровне с которого ты заходишь. ес-но в папке префаба нет объекта. Мне пришлось написать точный путь до объекта и все заработало. Просто не думал я что он не будет искать везде...

Comment: За использование `GameObject.Find` вообще судить по 205ой статье нужно.

Comment: Почему? Блин я уже закомитил с GameObject.Find ((( Все меня точно не возьмут на работу))) ахаха

Comment: Дело в том, что у меня скрипт на камере висит, а все объекты я добавляю при помощи Find, поэтому я не могу воспользоваться этим вариантом, либо я еще не достаточно осведомлен как это делается. Я просто хочу уйти от бесячей фигни перетаскивания различных элементов ручками при запуске игры. Не думаю что Find это такая плохая идея - так как я его все равно использую однажды в основном при инициализации сцены или странички UI а не в loop - обработчиках.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему, но помогло точное указание пути до объекта в иерархии префаба:
Получается глупо то, что я использую Find, но при этом указываю точный путь до этого объекта. Почему так не известно, возможно из за того, что это префаб, так как аналогичный вариант вполне работает НЕ с префабами

```
Следующий вариант оказался рабочим:

GameObject Nickname = prefab.transform.Find("ScrollViewOfMainMenu/Viewport/Content/VerticalLayout/Nickname_text").gameObject;
```